# A way to measure Smoothness of a time series dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe of large grouped data. I am able to visualise the dataframe with plotly but I would like to identify the "smoothness" of the dataframe without having to visualise the data.I researched and saw that a potential way to go is using difference of standard deviation.Is there a way of calculating sort of a smooth index based on how the time series data is so as to separate smooth data from noisy data.Two examples of my dataframe visuals are;

Smooth (no noise)

[image]

Rough (noise)

[image]

Comment: a smooth secular decline in a time series value would bias standard deviation upwards, your series would have to be stationary for this sort of comparison to work

Comment: What if i have a set of fixed datapoijts e.g 100 datapoints for each.can we compare on this basis if i choose to have fixed set of datapoints

Comment: Maybe you could get the Fourier transform data for the noise, and then try looking at the average of the standard deviations of the linear regression data from the original data set for a set of evenly spaced intervals that form a partition on the time domain.  I'm not familiar with that software, though.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, one should be wary of what they mean by smoothness of a curve. Mathematically, smoothness is (loosely speaking) a measure of the number of continuous derivatives over its domain of definition. But, from your question, it is evident that it is not what you are looking for. Instead, I think you want to measure the "roughness" of the curve.

One way of doing so is to compute the sum of the squared difference of the normalized differences. The result is that, the closer you are to 0 the smoother the curve. It might not be the best of all measures, but it does a pretty good job and is easily applicable AND it is scale invariant.

So, here is an example: I'll give you three time series. A parabolic function (`x**2`), a random curve and a flat line. I create the time series and convert them to dataframes (not the nicest way to do it, maybe, but it works).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-50,50,1)
y = x**2

ts1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100), index=pd.date_range("1/1/2000", periods=100))
ts2 = pd.Series(y, index=pd.date_range("1/1/2000", periods=100))
ts3 = pd.Series(1,index=pd.date_range("1/1/2000", periods=100) )

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ts1.index, columns=['Date'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=ts1.values, columns=['Values'])
df_s = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=ts2.index, columns=['Date'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data=ts2.values, columns=['Values'])
df_r = pd.merge(df3, df4, left_index=True, right_index=True)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(data=ts3.index, columns=['Date'])
df6 = pd.DataFrame(data=ts3.values, columns=['Values'])
df_l = pd.merge(df5, df6, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

So, `df_s` is the random curve:

[image]

`df_r` is the parabola:

[image]

and `df_l` is the line:

[image]

Now, the function you should compute has the following form:

```
f = df['Values'].diff()
Normed_f = (f-f.mean())/f.std()
roughness_ts = (Normed_f.diff() ** 2).sum()
```

In our cases,

```
f_1 = df_s['Values'].diff()
Normed_f_1 = (f_1-f_1.mean())/f_1.std()
roughness_ts1 = (Normed_f_1.diff() ** 2)
roughness_ts1.sum()

f_2 = df_r['Values'].diff()
Normed_f_2 = (f_2-f_2.mean())/f_2.std()
roughness_ts2 = (Normed_f_2.diff() ** 2)
roughness_ts2.sum()

f_3 = df_l['Values'].diff()
Normed_f_3 = (f_3-f_3.mean())/f_3.std()
roughness_ts3 = (Normed_f_3.diff() ** 2)
roughness_ts3.sum()

roughness_ts1.sum(),roughness_ts2.sum(),roughness_ts3.sum()
```

which returns:

```
(275.2340106887092, 0.11878787878787875, 0.0)
```

Another way (which I find harder to get a feeling for) is autocorrelation lag 1, which basically compares data points with one another by shifting the curve. This makes it possible to see if consecutive points have a relation.

```
ts1.autocorr(lag=1), ts2.autocorr(lag=1),ts3.autocorr(lag=1)
```

which returns:

```
(0.04990543648691135, 0.9969518319659281, nan)
```

The closer to 1 the score is the smoother the curve, the closer to 0 the "rougher" the curve. As you see, it return `nan` for constant functions.